# Jquery - auto close div when other one gets open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Auto close div is not working when other one gets open. Here is the html code,

```
<div class="item">
       <p>DJ Rizmo Ft. Omi & Kid Ink - Cheerleader (Remix)<br>
       <button class="bt-play" onclick="openPlayer('N9l-tHPOEOw')"> Play </button></p>
</div>
<br><div id="playN9l-tHPOEOw"></div>

<div class="item">
       <p>Cheerleader (remix) - By Omi feat Kid Ink<br>
       <button class="bt-play" onclick="openPlayer('-w_AjZ_CQuM')"> Play </button></p>
</div>
<br><div id="play-w_AjZ_CQuM"></div>

<div class="item">
       <p>Kid ink ft Omi Cheerleader Remix<br>
       <button class="bt-play" onclick="openPlayer('aAS1VMvf3tc')"> Play </button></p>
</div>
<br><div id="playaAS1VMvf3tc"></div>
```

Here goes the jquery code:

```
 function openPlayer(a) {
     var b = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/',
         c = "" + b + a,
         d = '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
         e = "" + c + d;
     $("#play" + a)
         .empty(e)
         .append(e)
         .play("open")
 };
```

Can anyone modify the jquery code, so that it shows only one #div closing the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added 2 lines to your code.

`$('div[id^="play"]').empty().hide()` takes all `div's` that have an Id that starts with "play" and hide them.

`.show()` is added after the `.append(e)`

```js
function openPlayer(a) {
  var b = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/',
    c = "" + b + a,
    d = '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    e = "" + c + d;
  $('div[id^="play"]').empty().hide()
  $("#play" + a)
    .empty(e)
    .append(e)
    .show()
    .play("open")
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <p>DJ Rizmo Ft. Omi & Kid Ink - Cheerleader (Remix)<br>
    <button class="bt-play" onclick="openPlayer('N9l-tHPOEOw')"> Play </button></p>
</div>
<br>
<div id="playN9l-tHPOEOw"></div>

<div class="item">
  <p>Cheerleader (remix) - By Omi feat Kid Ink<br>
    <button class="bt-play" onclick="openPlayer('-w_AjZ_CQuM')"> Play </button></p>
</div>
<br>
<div id="play-w_AjZ_CQuM"></div>

<div class="item">
  <p>Kid ink ft Omi Cheerleader Remix<br>
    <button class="bt-play" onclick="openPlayer('aAS1VMvf3tc')"> Play </button></p>
</div>
<br>
<div id="playaAS1VMvf3tc"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Carsten Løvbo Andersen. Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

```
function openPlayer(a){
    $('div.item').hide() //It's example function i don't know how u want close this
    $(this).closest('.item').show() //This is save open handle div
    var b='<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/',c=""+b+a,d='" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',e=""+c+d;$("#play"+a).empty(e).append(e).play("open")
};
```

Comment: it hides everything including the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you only hide the `div`, youtube will play in background(you will hear the sound). So use `empty()` before `hide()`, try below code.

```
function openPlayer(a) {
$("div[id^="play"]").empty().hide();
  var b = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/',
c = "" + b + a,
d = '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
e = "" + c + d;
 $("#play" + a)
.empty(e)
.append(e)
.show()
.play("open")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your js:

```
$('div[id^="play"]').empty();
```

I would rather suggest you have play div and append your frame inside the play div with the id you are passing so that you can clear play div everytime. But any how the above works.

See the bin link:
http://jsbin.com/fagayaj/1/edit?html,js,output